# IF statement to search for graphics path

Tags: graphics

Is it possible to have more than 1 graphics path in a TeX file and have latex search in more than one at the same time? I'm asking because I access my files over multiple devices (on Dropbox), and the path is slightly different in each case.

Something along what the simplified code below does:

```
    if 
    *path1 exists* then
    \graphicspath{path1}

    else if 
    *path2 exists* then
    \graphicspath{path2}
    end
```

Many thanks
W

Comment: Can you just use all the paths `\graphicspath{{path1},{path2}}`? Unless the directories are very large or your computer is very slow, you should not notice the speed difference of searching all of them (it does not matter if they exist or not).

Comment: @samcarter no comma

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for this information - I did not know that! I was using it for years with comma (copied from one project to the next). This is probably not showing any errors as it searches for a folder called `,`?